# SoundCloud: Authentication when the web server is local

Tags: authentication, soundcloud

I've created an app that uses Javascript and php. The php is hosted on an apache server which is located in my house and is not accessible from outside. To start the 'app' I just point my browser at

```
http://server-ip-address/my-app
```

The problem I'm having is with SoundCloud Authentication.

If I'm using a browser on the same machine as the apache server then I can authenticate using a redirect URL of

```
http://localhost/my-app/callback.html
```

and setting this in the app settings on soundcloud.com and the initialise function in the SDK.

The problem is, what if I'm not running the browser on the same machine as the apache server? The app is a remote control for a music player, hence the server will generally be running on a headless PC and the app will be accessed from another device. There seems to be no way to get Authentication to work in both these scenarios since the URI I send in the initialise function has to match the one on the soundcloud app settings and I have no way of knowing what server-ip-address will be for everyone who might use the app.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do have a way of locating that server (with static IP or some dynamic DNS service) you won't be able to authenticate – SoundCloud has to pass the oauth_token somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit disappointing to find that out though. Guess I'll have to shelve my plans to add SoundCloud support :(